# NSManagedObjectContext deadlocking from 2 serial queues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

I've created a system where i can request an NSManagedObjectContext from a singleton object, dependant on the queue it's running on. Every serial GCD dispatch queue is associated with a certain task, and thus gets its own context, though all with the same persistent store coordinator.

I was under the assumption that this would solve my problems associated with threads, which it so far seems to have done, but now i have a different problem: If 2 serial queues, with different MOCs, both try to make the context execute, they both lock and the app freezes. So what did i miss?

"...[I]f you create one context per thread, but all pointing to the same persistent store coordinator, Core Data takes care of accessing the coordinator in a thread-safe way (the lock and unlock methods of NSManagedObjectContext handle recursion)." ([source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html))

What i read there, is that Core Data should handle locking and unlocking correctly with my setup. Or do i understand 'in a thread-safe way' wrong in this case?

Edit: I basically have a dictionary that maps a queue to a context. At first i wanted to work with threads instead of queues, until i read this part:

"Note: You can use threads, serial operation queues, or dispatch queues for concurrency. For the sake of conciseness, this article uses “thread” throughout to refer to any of these." ([source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JeremyP is right: queues do not == threads. A queue may create a new thread for each operation - Core Data (in the default mode) requires thread confinement (that is, the thread that created the `NSManagedObjectContext` must be the thread used for all access to any objects from that context).

You may want to check how the confinement options are used - if you're targeting iOS5 alone, you might be able to change it without too much difficulty and still use the queues.

Comment: Yea, i noticed an option to confine by Queue. I now took an approach that isn't possibly as fast as the system i had in mind, but a lot safer; One fetch context which gets updated whenever a save context saves. Only problem is that i have to make a copy of the ManagedObject before passing it along, since it might invalidate before my other objects are done with it...

Answer (score 2):

If by "serial queue" you mean GCD dispatch queue or `NSOperationQueue`, you are making incorrect assumptions that each queue has a dedicated thread or that the tasks for each queue always run on the same thread.

You need to figure out a way of mapping a thread to a managed object context, perhaps by way of an NSDictionary and when you run a task on your queue, get the MOC associated with the current thread.

Comment: What i've done is what you're suggesting, but with GCD dispatch queues instead of threads. Also see my last edit.

Comment: @Erik: you say you map a queue to a context.  You should map each thread to a context IMO.

Comment: That was my first assumption, but according to that quote queues would work fine too, so that's why i was wondering. I'll try to rewrite the mapping method so it uses threads instead of queues later today.

Comment: By the way, if i pause and check the stack trace, they are 2 different queues running on 2 different threads. I know that in general this does not have to be the case, but then why does it lock in this case?